# How to define the way of go in a constraint? GLPK

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming

I have the following constraint in the mathematical model

$$
\sum\limits_{j|(j,i)\in A}y_{ji} - \sum\limits_{j|(i, j)\in A}y_{ij} = 
\Bigg\{
\begin{matrix} d_iz_i & \mbox{ } \forall i \in C 
\\
\sum\limits_{i\in C}-d_iz_i &  i = 0
\end{matrix}
$$
How to implement this constraint in GLPK so that according to the value of i, the model behaves it correctly obeying the range of i?

> Remembering that my difficulty is only in separate interactions

Somebody help me?

Comment: The decision variable is a matrix $\mathrm Y$. You will have to vectorize the matrix if you want to have a decision vector. This looks like network flow. You should provide context.

Comment: Yes, this is a matrix binary. I only wanted a idea of how implement the right side of the constraint to different values of i.

Comment: It is a simple $if$ statement. See Erwin's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
subject to
   e{i in I}: ... = if i=0 then sum{j in C} -p[j]*z[j] else p[i]*z[i];
```

I assume the set `I` is `0..n` and `C` is `1..n`.